# Web part in only Document Library pages

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I've built a web part for SharePoint 2010.

Using SharePoint Designer I've got it to work on every page within the site, but then I realized that I only want it to work when users navigate document libraries.

Is there any way to do that? If not, how can I check that condition from the web part?

Answer (score 0):

> Using SharePoint Designer I've got it
>   to work on every page within the site

Does this mean you have embedded it in the master page?

A quick and dirty way; you could check the url for `/Forms/` and only show it then.